# Ketone reduction in presence of epoxy group

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

In the following reaction:

[image]

According to me we can use HSCH2CH2SH, followed by Raney Ni

But the answer is that we cannot achieve this conversion by that reagents . Why we cannot use them?

Comment: Thiols can open epoxides, perhaps preferentially to reaction with the ketone

Comment: As mentioned in comment, under the conditions required to form the dithiane, the thiol will likely open the epoxide and probably cause polymerisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first react the epoxide with HCl to form the halohydrin (reversible), followed by Clemmensen reduction which selectively reduces ketones and aldehydes to alkanes (no effect on the halohydrin), before finally restoring the epoxide by adding base.